# Store stdout and stderr logs of Azure App Service into Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to store logs of Node.js web application (basically whole output of stdout and stderr) to the Azure Blob Storage. I've tried turning stuff on in **App Service logs**, **Diagnostic  settings** but nothing seems to work. The only way how I can store logs (however not in Blob storage but on the App Service File System) is by using `Application Logging (Filesystem)` option. The problem with this option is that it is automatically turned off after 12 hours.

It is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-windows) that they only support .NET applications but I am not sure that I've understood it correctly. It seemed to me that such a essential functionality must be somehow supported.

So I wanted to ask, is there some other way or library that can be used for storing logs of Node.js web app in the Blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach for logging with an **Azure App Service** is usually **Application Insights** (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-retention-privacy) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights) for more information).  You can configure retention policies for blob storage (if needed beyond the defaults)